# What is the difference of over and for in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

1. I have studied English for 3 years.
2. I have studied English over 3 years.

What is the difference of over and for in this sentence?

Comment: _'**I have studied English over 3 years.**'_ means that the subject has taken 3 years to learn English. It took him 3 years to learn the language, either fully or fluently, or upto his personal expectation.

Answer (score 3):

If you use *for*, you are saying that you have performed an action (in this case, studying English) for (approximately) three years.

The *over* sentence is tricky. One could say:

> I have studied English **for over** three years.

which would mean the speaker has studied English for some period *longer than* three years, as opposed to *approximately* three years.

Or, one could say:

> I have studied English **over** [a span of] three years.

which would mean that, at some three-year part of the speaker's life, the person studied English. However, I think that sentence sounds awkward, and would read more natural if the *have* were removed, and some kind of clarification were inserted between *over* and *three years*:

> I studied English over a period of three years.

One could also say:

> I studied English **over** three years **ago**.

which would mean the speaker spent some undetermined amount of time studying English, but that happened more than three years ago.

The preposition *over* can be tricky here, but sometimes context might make it more clear what the speaker means. Analyzed in isolation, it can be hard to describe all the "differences" between a two such phrases.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>NOTE: I use *DURATION* below to designate a temporal measure, such as *three years* or *ten minutes*.</sub>

*For DURATION* and *over DURATION* are not interchangeable. This is in part because bare *over DURATION* will ordinarily be parsed as *for a period **longer than** DURATION*; but it is primarily because they are ordinarily used in different contexts.

- *For DURATION* implicates (I’ll explain that odd term shortly) an activity which you performed in some sense *continuously* during a timespan of length *DURATION*.

  > I have studied English for three years.

  (I qualify this with "in some sense" because it doesn't mean that you never slept or ate, or that every available hour was spent performing the activity; it means that you spent an appropriate amount of time on the activity *throughout* the timespan.)

  However, continuous performance is an implicature, not an entailment: that is, continuity is the ‘default’ interpretation, but this may be ‘cancelled’ by an explicit statement to the contrary:

  > I have studied English off and on for three years.

  With *for*, the timespan may be (as it is here) indeterminate: you *may* specify when it occurred (e.g. “for the last three years”), but you are not required to.
- *Over DURATION*  implicates *discrete* actions you performed during *DURATION*.

  > I have read seven English novels over those three years.
  >   Over the last two hours I have called four times, and no one has answered.

  With *over*, the timespan is almost always determinate—even with a perfect construction which implicates the timespan leading up to reference time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes speakers will use **over** in temporal contexts to mean "more than".

> You can't get a parking space in the company garage until you have worked there **over six months**.
>
> I'm no stranger to this place. I've lived here **over twenty years**.

This is a colloquial use.